# How to catch all errors in a particular Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I have a few services in angular that are in charge of tracking and counting things. I want to make sure that if there is ever an exception in any of these services it gracefully handled and does not affect the rest of the code, but I want to keep my error handling limited and specific to these services. Is there a nice way to do that?

I am aware of $exceptionHandler, but that is too global. I only want to catch exceptions that can happen in my tracking service which exposes about 20 methods or so without repeating code for each method.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Sina

Answer (score 0):

If your service methods are making `$http` requests, you can set up an [AngularJS HTTP Interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

There is a very nice example in the 'Interceptors' section of this article that shows you how setup methods that will capture any `$http` request and/or response errors.

From here you could handle how you want to react to and handle any errors.

Comment: I want catch all expcetions. Things that can cause exceptions can be anything. For example trying to access properties of null or undefined argument. 

i.e.
```
function trackProductImpression(item) {
  dataLayer.push( {
    id: item.id
  })
}
```
if the item is null this can throw an exception. And I want to be able to catch all of these errors and not stop the code that called the tracking service.

Comment: From my understanding of AngularJS, `$exceptionHandler` is the only way to globally handle exceptions, and HTTP interceptors are the only way to globally handle HTTP exceptions.